# SMTP traffic being forwarded through SSH even do AllowTcpForwarding is disabled

Tags: ssh-tunneling, sshd, openssh

I have a situation on one server, where it seems to be spaming over traffic being sent over SSH tunnel.

Output below shows connections being made to remote SMTP server that seem to be initiated over SSH

```
[~]# lsof -i | grep smtp | grep ssh | tail -5
sshd      1015801            root    6u  IPv4 2949384874      0t0  TCP hostname:47778->col0-mc4-f.col0.hotmail.com:smtp (ESTABLISHED)
sshd      1015801            root   10u  IPv4 2949384887      0t0  TCP hostname:44950->bay0-mc5-f.bay0.hotmail.com:smtp (ESTABLISHED)
sshd      1015801            root   12u  IPv4 2949384892      0t0  TCP hostname:44001->bay0-mc5-f.bay0.hotmail.com:smtp (ESTABLISHED)
sshd      1018332            root    9u  IPv4 2949372697      0t0  TCP hostname:53717->38.102.228.18:smtp (SYN_SENT)
sshd      1018394            root    6u  IPv4 2949396212      0t0  TCP hostname:39489->mailcluster.midco.net:smtp (ESTABLISHED)
```

TCPForwarding is disabled on the server, and I have also tried reinstalling openssh completely.

```
 [~]# egrep -i "tcp|forward" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
AllowAgentForwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
#X11Forwarding yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
```

How is it possible for the traffic to be tunneled over SSH if it is suppose to be disabled?

Am I reading something wrong here, does this show SMTP traffic being forwarded over SSH?

Is there possibly some include file for ssh config?

I know the server needs to be rebuilt, as it has obviously been rooted, but I am interested here in finding out how is this happening exactly.

I made a tcpdump with

`tcpdump -vv -x -X -n -s 1500 -i em1 'port number' >> /root/tcpdump.ssh`

and I can see ip addresses making connections, and active ssh processes, but I still don't know how exactly are they forwarding the traffic.

any ideas anyone, on how is the traffic being forwarded even do it is suppose to be disabled?

Comment: Set `LogLevel` to  `DEBUG` and `grep -i "port forwarding" <sshd-log-file>` : https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/51a1c2115265c6e80ede8a5c9dccada9aeed7143/session.c#L368

Comment: doesn't seem to log forwarding. I set LogLevel DEBUG, restarted ssh, and unblocked the ips in question, and can see smpt over ssh in lsof again, but forwarding doesn't seem to get logged, in secure or messages log, i do see ips being logged in secure like "sshd[502922]: Connection from 81.2.236.140 port 56217 on ip:port"

Comment: Did try to forward a port yourself? Try `ssh hostname -L 2525:col0-mc4-f.col0.hotmail.com:25` , then connect to `localhost:2525`. Will ssh print error?

Comment: Perhaps someone is running a second `sshd` process with customized config? http://serverfault.com/questions/344295/is-it-possible-to-run-sshd-as-a-normal-user

Comment: ssh hostname -L 2525:col0-mc4-f.col0.hotmail.com:25 just logs me in, no process gets created on port 2525, I can't connect to that port or see it in netstat. There is no alternate sshd process with different config as far as I can see, there is only one process listening on port defined in sshd_config, and if I stop or reset it to default port, it stops forwarding, when remote ips are unblocked

Comment: My 2 previous comments unrelated to each other. Yous say it just logs you in - now on client, not server machine open another terminal window and try to connect to localhost:2525 using telnet or something. Will ssh in first terminal window print an error?